# How to check if message is delivered using Push Notifications in laravel

Tags: android, laravel, push-notification, laravel-5

I want to know how to check if the message is being delivered at the recipient end or not. I am using [this](https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification) library but not able to figure out how to solve this issue. I have integrated laravel 5.2

The main issue is sometimes message sent from the server but in-app it does not receive. Is there any other way or any alternative to get out of this issue?

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Push notifications are read by services. If the service does not receive or actively listen it shouldnt be possible.

Comment: What if I don't want to create services at recipient end. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Not unless push notifications are read and displayed on firebase notification console.

Answer (score 0):

From your server you can only know if you sent the message succesfully to the google server but not if google sent it to the phone. you could create add a method in your rest service to send a kind of status when the notification come to the phone in your MessagingService class.

Comment: Is this could be reliable solution, as per I think too many rest services could cause delay in the system